# How to change requested Url from current Url In MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to MVC4. I want to send a link for change password form from forgot password form. When i am clicking reset button in Forgot password form it should send a absolute url for change password. Now my link in forgot password is ://localhost:59523/Login/Forgotpassword?Length=5.Now I want to send a link to user link  ://localhost:59523/Login/Changepassword. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my controller code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        mail.To.Add(_check_email);
                        mail.From = new MailAddress("sample@gmail.com");
                        mail.Subject = ("Reset Your Password");
                        var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
                        var random_code = new Random();
                        var code = new string(
                            Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                                      .Select(s => s[random_code.Next(s.Length)])
                                      .ToArray());

                        //storing password reset code into database
                        var query = db.Tbl_Users.Where(u => u.ResetPwdCode ==code).FirstOrDefault();
                        query.ResetPwdCode = code;
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        string absolute_url = ---------->>>>>Here is the problem
                        string link = absolute_url + "?=" + code;

                        string htmlBody;
htmlBody ="Mail Body";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        mail.Body = htmlBody;
                        smtp.Send(mail);

                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Check your mail to reset your password");
                        return View("Forgotpassword");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string absolute_url = Url.Action("Changepassword", "Login", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Comment: I just want in Controller. I have added my code. please refer it and help me

Comment: Yes it is working, Thank you. Now i am doing in localserver, If i host this project on WWW, It will work?